# implementing quagga scanning barcodes

Tags: web, barcode, scanning, quagga

I am making an online scan application just with HTML5 and javascript using Quagga.js.

I need to get the webcam working for searching barcodes and imported quagga.js :

On the web page of quagga you'll find a method called Quagga.init. to initialize the webcam view. 
I entered in the script tags this code :

```
Quagga.init({
    inputStream : {
      name : "Live",
      type : "LiveStream"
    },
    decoder : {
      readers : ["code_128_reader"]
    }
  }, function() {
      console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
      Quagga.start();
  });
```

But nothing happened. 
What do I need to do to get this webcam working? 
Any other opinions to create a web-based application for scanning barcodes ?

Thank you for answering !

Answer (score 4):

Include `<div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>` into your markup.

Answer (score 3):

It's a few months old question but Eugene's answer is not full. For me, to make QuaggaJS work I had to add video tag as well:

```
<div id="interactive" class="viewport">
    <video autoplay="true" preload="auto"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your console?

Using "Livestream" (Access to Camera) requires you to have a SSL certified website.
It means the additional "s" in  https://

You can read more about it here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2580401?hl=sv

You should also know that you can get a free SSL certificat, but you need to have access to your server. Most hosting services can help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Add in html

```
<div id="barcode-scanner" class="size"> </div>
```

Add in JavaScript

```
 Quagga.init({           
        inputStream : {
            name : "Live",
            type : "LiveStream",
            target: document.querySelector('#barcode-scanner'), 
             constraints: {
                width: 520,
                height: 400,                  
                facingMode: "user"  //"environment" for back camera, "user" front camera
                }               
        },                         
        decoder : {
            readers : ["code_128_reader","code_39_reader"]
        }

    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            esto.error = err;
            console.log(err);
                return
        }

        Quagga.start();

        Quagga.onDetected(function(result) {                              
                var last_code = result.codeResult.code;                   
                    console.log("last_code "); 
             });
    });
```

Works for me in Vue.

Comment: How about the select Barcode Type from Dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

Add a div element like this in your markup:

```
<div id="barcode_canvas"></div>
```

Then include the target in your input stream like this:
`target: document.querySelector('#barcode_canvas')`

```
          Quagga.init({
              inputStream : {
                name : 'Live',
                type : 'LiveStream',
                target: document.querySelector('#barcode_canvas')
              },
              decoder : {
                readers : ['ean_reader']
              }
            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return
                }
                console.log('Initialization finished. Ready to start');
                Quagga.start();                     
            });
```